# How to solve for x when both sides have the variable and one is negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’ve come across the question $2x-1=-x+1$ when solving for the $x$-coordinate of two linear equations. I’m unsure of how to go about finding the value of $x$ when there are not only $2$ variables on each side, but one is also a negative. I know from looking at the answers that it is supposed to equal $0.6$ but when I complete it, I always get to $-0.6$. I get here by first adding $1$ to each side, then dividing by $-1$ before taking $x$ away and finally dividing by the remaining $-3$:
$$2x-1=-x+1$$

$$2x=-x+1+1$$

$$\frac{2x}{-1} = \frac{-x+2}{-1}$$

$$-2x-x=x+2-x$$

$$\frac{-3x}{-3}=\frac{2}{-3}$$

$$x=-0.6$$

Can anyone explain what I did wrong here or how I’m supposed to go about converting the $-0.6$ to a positive? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: After adding +1 to both sides, your right-hand side was 
$$
-x +1 +1 = -x+2
$$
Then you divide both sides by $-1$, which in your solution resulted in a right-hand side of 
$$
x+2
$$
See where the mistake is?

Comment: The shortcut is to start with $2x - 1 = -x + 1$ and then add $x$ to both the LHS and RHS.  Then add $+1$ to both the LHS and RHS.

Comment: Oh yeah, I completely forgot to divide the 2 by the -1, that makes so much more sense now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please add LaTeX/MathJax formatting to your question! Thanks! For reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164

Comment: +1 to your question, taking it from -1 to 0.  Using Sherlock Holmes methodology (i.e. when you eliminate the impossible...), I have discovered why questions such as yours are being anonymously downvoted, despite the significant work that you showed in your question.  You **neglected** to set up a zoom session so that the anonymous downvoter could watch you do jumping jacks.

Comment: @user2661923 Downvoted for lack of MathJax formatting! I had already left a note in comments!

Comment: @MathStackExchange Have you ever seen anyone else downvote a question from a new user, less than $5$ minutes after a mathjax comment was left, solely because mathjax was not used?

Comment: @user2661923 Downvote and comment were almost simultaneously. Law is the same for us all! Any improvement will result in a change of my vote. As I'm expressing my downvote right, it's only my choice to downvote, upvote or leave it as it is, judging my standards and my understanding of moderation by community principles.

Comment: Problem remediated! Downvote reverted! Please use MathJax in the future when asking questions or posting answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2x - 1 = -x + 1, you can simply add +x and +1 to both sides. This gives you 2x - 1 + x + 1 = -x + 1 + x + 1, which leads to 3x = 2 and therefore x = 2/3.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please add LaTeX/MathJax formatting to your question! Thanks! For reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164

Comment: What you did wrong:  When you divided both sides with -1 (with 2x = -x + 2), you didn’t correctly divide the right hand side. (-x + 2) / -1 = x - 2. Maybe you just forgot the parentheses. :D